# Relative path in absolute URI: java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1823)

Tags: java, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a package named **tester** in pl/sql. But I got the following message.

**Relative path in absolute URI: java.net.URI.checkPath(URI.java:1823)**

```
--Package Declaration

create or replace PACKAGE tester AS
    PROCEDURE Hello;
END tester;
/

--Package Body

create or replace PACKAGE BODY tester AS
   PROCEDURE Hello
   IS
       BEGIN
           dbms_output.put_line('Hello...');
   END Hello;
END tester;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening a new blank Sql Developer worksheet and paste your package sql in there and run it to compile.